# Red cargo ship with pier and a tower crane set?

Tags: set-identification

When I was a child (~15-20 years ago) I remember I had a LEGO set composed by a red cargo ship, with a pier and a tower crane that supposedly moved blocks from the pier to the ship.

The name of the ship was Titan, or Atlantic I think.

Can someone find the name of the LEGO set and maybe a picture?

Comment: I know of the set that you are speaking of, it was one of the city sets in the late 80s or early 90s. I don't have time to hunt it down myself right now, but you can go look on [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-City/year-2018), they have a comprehensive catalogue of almost every Lego set that has been released. You should be able to find it pretty easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your description, the set is [Launch and Load Seaport (6542)](https://brickset.com/sets/6542-1/Launch-Load-Seaport):

[image: 6542]

It was released in 1991, and it matches everything you described including a ship called "Atlantic", so this has to be it. If you're looking for some nostalgia, you can pick this up [on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6542-1) for ~$150.